# Openlayers map tiles are not initially loaded in single page app

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, openlayers-5

I have a single page application built with

- Express (4.16.3),
- Openlayers (5.3) and
- Pug (2.0.3 – formerly known as Jade) templating engine.

The map container is loaded and has child elements with `ol-` classes as well as the zoom controls in the upper left corner. So the Openlayers script is successfully executed. **But it doesn't show the map tiles on load.**

When I resize the browser the map tiles show up all of a sudden. So I'm wondering:

What is the event that triggers the sudden rendering of the tiles on browser resize, and how can I trigger it myself so the map is getting displayed correctly on load?

My `index.pug` looks like this:

```
doctype html
html(lang='de')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='ie=edge')
    meta(
      name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    title=`myTitle`

    // Stylesheets
    link(
      rel='stylesheet',
      href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css')
    link(
      rel='stylesheet',
      href='/assets/style.css')

    // Scripts
    script(src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js')
    script(src='https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList')
    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')
    script(data-main='/js/main', src='/js/require.js')

  body
    include header
    include tabs

    main
      #loader Loading...
      include map

    include footer
```

And in the `main` part you see the `map` pug template included that looks like this:

```
section.component#component-map
  #map.map
  script.
    /**
    * Leaflet Map
    */
    // Create markers and geodata
    const mapCenter = [13.429, 52.494];
    const siteData = !{JSON.stringify(sites)};
    const features = siteData.map(site => {
      return {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [ Number(site.longitude), Number(site.latitude) ]
        }
      }
    });

    const image = new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: null,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: "red", width: 1})
    });

    const styles = {
      "Point": new ol.style.Style({
        "image": image
      })
    }
    const styleFunction = function(feature) {
      return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    };

    const geojsonObject = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": features
    };

    const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
    });

    const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    });

    const map = new ol.Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        vectorLayer
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(mapCenter),
        zoom: 17,
      })
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Graham Thanks. I reduced the question to one single issue

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is probably an OpenLayers questions, your pug looks good from that perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself. My "solution" is more of a workaround than an actual solution. I wait for the map script to be executed (which is the case when the map container has a child element with class name `ol-viewport`) and then I trigger the browser `resize` event manually. Other than I expected, the `map.render()` or `map.renderSync()` methods do not load the tiles.
So the workaround looks like this:

```
const waitForMap = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.ol-viewport').length) {
      console.log("Exists!");
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      clearInterval(waitForMap);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: You just ended 3 weeks of frustration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly but this solution saved me. I'm not using jQuery so replaced .length() with:

```js
const waitForMap = setInterval(function() {
    const e = document.querySelector(".ol-viewport");
    const cr = e.getClientRects(); 
    if ((cr.length != 0) && (cr[0].width != 0) && (cr[0].height != 0)) {
        console.log("Render OpenLayer map");
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        clearInterval(waitForMap);
    }
}, 500);
```